# Replace word in Java

Tags: java, regex

There is some line, for example "1 qqq 4 aaa 2" and list {aaa, qqq}. I must change all words (consists only from letters) on words from list. Answer on this example "1 aaa 4 qqq 2". Try

```
StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(str, " ");
while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()){
    tmp = tokenizer.nextToken();
    if(tmp.matches("^[a-z]+$"))
        newStr = newStr.replaceFirst(tmp, words.get(l++));
}
```

But it's not working. In result I have the same line.

All my code:

```
String space = " ", tmp, newStr;
Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
while (stdin.hasNextLine()) {
    int k = 0, j = 0, l = 0;
    String str = stdin.nextLine();
    newStr = str;
    List<String> words = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(str.split(" ")));
    words.removeIf(new Predicate<String>() {
        @Override
        public boolean test(String s) {
            return !s.matches("^[a-z]+$");
        }
    });
    Collections.sort(words);
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(str, " ");
    while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()){
        tmp = tokenizer.nextToken();
        if(tmp.matches("^[a-z]+$"))
            newStr = newStr.replaceFirst(tmp, words.get(l++));
    }
    System.out.printf(newStr);
}
```

Comment: Can you try org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.replace()?

Comment: @Hua Promblem is that first word change on correct(in this example aaa), but when I need to change second aaa, program change the word it input second ago and I have line from start. And no. I can use only standart java lib. Sorry for my terrible English.

Comment: You saved your results in newStr, which is NOT defined in the while loop. The second time you are in the loop, it's the resulting newStr you are working on.

Also whenever you can stay away from regex, please do so. It's slow and hard to maintain. 

Besides, I am not sure why you used tokenizer to break up your input first. It seems unnecessary.

Comment: Please post more of your code, this is not understandable. (Declaration of newStr, what is l++ ?) What is the input and what output do you expect?

Comment: @burna input any line. Output line with words(consist only with  letters) sorted by alphabet, and other words stay in there place and space's number equals to space's number in starting line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just out of curiosity, another solution (the others really don't answer the question), which takes the input line and sorts the words alphabetically in the result, as you commented in your question.

```
public class Replacer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Replacer r = new Replacer();

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (in.hasNextLine()) {
            System.out.println(r.replace(in.nextLine()));
        }    
    }

    public String replace(String input) {
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("([a-z]+)").matcher(input);    
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        List<String> replacements = new ArrayList<>();
        while (m.find()) {
            replacements.add(m.group());    
        }
        Collections.sort(replacements);    
        m.reset();

        for (int i = 0; m.find(); i++) {    
        m.appendReplacement(sb, replacements.get(i));
        }
        m.appendTail(sb);    

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where you was before i went to bed? It could be very helpful for me today at university, but I saw it only now =\ But ty)

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem might be that `replaceFirst()` expects a regular expression as first parameter and you are giving it a String.

Maybe try

```
newStr = newStr.replaceFirst("^[a-z]+$", words.get(l++));
```

instead?

**Update:**

Would that be a possibility for you:

```
    StringBuilder _b = new StringBuilder();     
    while (_tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()){
        String _tmp = _tokenizer.nextToken();
        if(_tmp.matches("^[a-z]+$")){
            _b.append(words.get(l++));
       }
       else{
            _b.append(_tmp);
       }
       _b.append(" ");
    }
    String newStr = _b.toString().trim();
```

**Update 2:**

Change the StringTokenizer like this:

```
StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(str, " ", true);
```

That will also return the delimiters (all the spaces).

And then concatenate the String like this:

```
    StringBuilder _b = new StringBuilder();     
    while (_tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()){
        String _tmp = _tokenizer.nextToken();
        if(_tmp.matches("^[a-z]+$")){
            _b.append(words.get(l++));
       }
       else{
            _b.append(_tmp);
       }
    }
    String newStr = _b.toString().trim();
```

That should work.

**Update 3:**

As @DavidConrad  mentioned `StrinkTokenizer` should not be used anymore. Here is another solution with `String.split()`:

```
final String[] _elements = str.split("(?=[\\s]+)");

int l = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < _tokenizer.length; i++){
    if(_tokenizer[i].matches("^[a-z]+$")){
        _b.append(_arr[l++]);
    }
    else{
        _b.append(_tokenizer[i]);     
    }
}
```

Comment: Thought so too, but `tmp` is `[a-z]+` that will cause no problem. With your method he will probably replace the first word over and over again.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. It's probably a problem with newStr.

Comment: @maraca Yes! And i don't know how to fix this

Comment: @Мари sorry I don't see why it would happen in your example, unless the words in your list are the same as those from the tokenizer.

Comment: @maraca They always the same because list consist from words from line    but sorted by alphabet. And program replace word for another, but when it must replace this "another" word, it replace word it inserted

Comment: @Мари: Updated my answer. Is that a possible solution?

Comment: @HendrikSimon Spaces. There numbers must be like in starting line

Comment: Yes, in this case constructing the new string is the safe solution, as Hendrik does, but you might want to insert some spaces.

Comment: @HendrikSimon It will be 1 space between words, won't it? But what if in starting line it was 3 or 4?

Comment: @Мари Updated the answer

Comment: Note: `StringTokenizer` is old and broken and should never be used by anyone for anything.

Comment: @DavidConrad So... How take words from line?

Comment: From the [`StringTokenizer` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html): `StringTokenizer` is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the `split` method of `String` or the `java.util.regex` package instead.

Comment: @DavidConrad Ty. I'll keep it in mine

Comment: @Мари @DavidConrad added another update with `String.split()`